# Angular 2, import custom package

Tags: node.js, angular, components

I'm using angular 2+, I have copy a custom package into my node_module directory like this node_module/@customPackage/forms
so in my component code I import it like this import {blabla}from '@customPackage/forms'. 
but at the compilation time I still have an error saying "[ts] cannot find module @customPackage/forms".

I really don't know why I have that error. Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi no you dont need to copy paste your package, The correct way to use your custom package into the angular application, is to link it like so:

**STEPS**:
1. inside your custom package folder:

- `yarn build`
- `yarn link` :
- this will display something like this(this is from my custom package) .

  - see the `yarn link "my-package`":

[image]

2. Now, go into your angular project folder and type the above sentence, to link your custom package into your angular project:

   - `yarn link "my-package"` (we need the double quotes around the package name)
     [image]
3. open your code editor, if you use `vscode` you should see the package into `node_modules` folder, **with a small arrow on the right** like so:
   [image]
4. **If you succeed on the above, you can now use your module like e.g `import { mymodule } from 'my-package`**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can write down package name in `dependencies` array in `package.json` file and after hit `npm install`.so install all dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the comment. No this is not an issue. That package is not on npm repository, It's a custom package that my team mate did. So I manually import it by copy/paste the package into the node_module folder